# Is there a way to create a new type from an union type with some it's options removed?

Tags: typescript

Let us say we have

```
type U = A | B | C
```

and we need type U without some of it's options

```
function f<T option U>(u: U): U without T {...}
```

How can we express that

1. U has type union
2. T is an option of U
3. The returned type is like U but without some option

?

Comment: What's an "option"?

Comment: It is the concept of T being part of union U. It is not real ts syntax

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475711/exclude-type-by-member-type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750647/get-type-of-union-by-discriminant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Type of Union By Discriminant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750647/get-type-of-union-by-discriminant)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use Exclude from stadard library.

```
type U = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type nonA = Exclude<U, 'a'>; // 'b' | 'c'
```

And for your function

```
function f<T extends U>(u: U): Exclude<U,T> {...}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types

Answer (score 0):

100% working example

```
function withoutType<U, T extends U>(u: U) {
  return u as Exclude<U, T>;
}

type Union = string | number | Function;
let x = 5;
let y = withoutType<Union, Function>(x); // let x: string | number;
```